# How attach code to a running iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, gdb

I am trying to fix a random hang in my iphone app. I could not regenerate the hang from launching it from the  xcode. Is their any way to attach xcode debugger, as soon as I detect the hang? (I can  attach it to 'instruments') but it did not much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't connect `gdb` to an already-running iPhone process. This *may* be possible if you jailbreak the phone.